# How to multiply a row of pandas df by a number n, keeping a delimeter in between?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas

I have a pandas df as below:

```
Type,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
Type1,test1,,test1 || test2,test4
Type2,never_mind1,,never_mind1 || never_mind4,
Type4,never_mind3,never_mind1,never_mind1 || never_mind2,
Type3,never_mind3,,,never_mind3
```

For the row where Type is Type1, the rest of the column should have n times their original value. The values should have the delimeter ' || ' . If the cell was blank then it should remain blank.

Below is the desired output for n = 3 :

```
Type,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
Type1,test1 || test1  || test1 ,,test1 || test2 || test1 || test2 || test1 || test2,test4 || test4 || test4
Type2,never_mind1,,never_mind1 || never_mind4,
Type4,never_mind3,never_mind1,never_mind1 || never_mind2,
Type3,never_mind3,,,never_mind3
```

Comment: can you please share the code that you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter rows by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and columns names by [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) and elementwise by [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) use lambda function with `np.repeat` only for non missing values:

```
n = 3
m = df["Type"].eq("Type1")
cols = df.columns.difference(['Type'])
repeat = lambda x: ' || '.join(np.repeat(x, n)) if pd.notna(x) else np.nan
df.loc[m, cols] = df.loc[m, cols].applymap(repeat)
print (df)
    Type                     Col1         Col2  \
0  Type1  test1 || test1 || test1          NaN   
1  Type2              never_mind1          NaN   
2  Type4              never_mind3  never_mind1   
3  Type3              never_mind3          NaN   

                                                Col3                     Col4  
0  test1 || test2 || test1 || test2 || test1 || t...  test4 || test4 || test4  
1                         never_mind1 || never_mind4                      NaN  
2                         never_mind1 || never_mind2                      NaN  
3                                                NaN              never_mind3
```

Comment: This solution is working for me. Can you also let me know if instead of selecting all cols, I need to slice for only col 1,2,3 how to do so ?

I am getting error :
"TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [3] of <class 'int'>" , 3 cause i was doing 3:20 in place of cols for my solution.

Comment: @PalashJhamb - then change `cols = df.columns.difference(['Type'])` to  `cols = ['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4']`

Comment: I did,  cols = cols[3:20] .  Its working.
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @PalashJhamb - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.join` with `applymap`:

```
n = 3
f = lambda x: " || ".join([x for _ in range(n)]) if pd.notna(x) else x
df.update(df[df["Type"].eq("Type1")].filter(like="Col").applymap(f))
```

Output:

```
    Type                     Col1         Col2                                               Col3                     Col4
0  Type1  test1 || test1 || test1          NaN  test1 || test2 || test1 || test2 || test1 || t...  test4 || test4 || test4
1  Type2              never_mind1          NaN                         never_mind1 || never_mind4                      NaN
2  Type4              never_mind3  never_mind1                         never_mind1 || never_mind2                      NaN
3  Type3              never_mind3          NaN                                                NaN              never_mind3
```